# Why does the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test fail in this case?

Tags: python, statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have these two time series, and I want to test if they come from the same distribution. So I applied the [`scipy.stats.ks_2samp()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) test. But the test returns a p-value of `0.0028`, whereas `describe()` gives these statistics:

```
count   120.000000  120.000000
mean    0.785867    0.774267
std     0.323941    0.304894
min     0.610000    0.610000
25%     0.619000    0.610000
50%     0.619000    0.619000
75%     0.749000    0.769500
max     1.812000    1.742000
```

So I don't get why the test rejects the null hypothesis, when mean and standard deviation are pretty similar. Also plots of the (cumulative) distributions look very similar.

Can anybody help me?

Here are my data and the test call:

```py
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[
    0.62, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62, 0.619, 0.61,
    0.619, 0.62, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62, 0.611, 0.62, 0.62, 0.61,
    0.619, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.642, 0.67, 0.749, 0.838, 0.862,
    0.804, 0.89, 0.942, 1.012, 1.13, 1.14, 1.191, 1.201, 1.123,
    1.299, 1.359, 1.411, 1.362, 1.352, 1.44,1.451, 1.46, 1.557,
    1.491, 1.622, 1.639, 1.787, 1.812, 1.665, 1.612, 1.253, 0.936,
    0.704, 0.643, 0.62, 0.619, 0.62, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.619,
    0.62, 0.61, 0.619, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.619, 0.62, 0.62,
    0.619, 0.62, 0.62, 0.619, 0.62, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62, 0.619,
    0.619, 0.619, 0.619, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62,
    0.619, 0.619, 0.619, 0.619, 0.61, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62, 0.619,
    0.61, 0.619, 0.619, 0.619, 0.619, 0.61, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62,
    0.619, 0.61, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62, 0.619, 0.749, 0.63, 0.62,
    0.61, 0.619, 0.619],
    [0.801, 0.644, 0.62, 0.62, 0.61, 0.61, 
    0.619, 0.62, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62,
    0.61, 0.619, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.62, 0.629, 0.689, 0.759,
    0.849, 0.84, 0.918, 1.019, 0.967, 0.92, 0.976, 1.089, 1.062,
    1.219, 1.202, 1.261, 1.387, 1.422, 1.39, 1.264, 1.281, 1.35,
    1.32, 1.419, 1.568, 1.554, 1.623, 1.592, 1.709, 1.742, 1.535,
    1.123, 0.84, 0.682, 0.63, 0.62, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62,
    0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.61, 0.619, 0.61,
    0.62, 0.61, 0.62, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.62, 0.61,
    0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.61, 0.61,
    0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62, 0.62, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61,
    0.619, 0.619, 0.619, 0.61, 0.618, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.61,
    0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.619, 0.619, 0.62, 0.61, 0.619, 0.62,
    0.62, 0.61, 0.619, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61]]).T

print(stats.ks_2samp(df.iloc[:, 1], df.iloc[:, 0]).pvalue)
```

Comment: Running your code gives a p-value of `0.999`, as expected. But note that you have time series, which do not each come from one simple distribution anyway, because there is obviously a dependency from the previous values in each series. So the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is not appropriate.

Comment: Yes maybe becasue I postedthe wrong data =) I' am sry. To make the data more readable I dropped the end of the two time series where the values were constant and close to 0.5. Maybe this can be the reason why the test fails? Can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test did not fail. The seemingly flat tails of the two series really are substantially different from each other. We can see this by zooming in on the tails (starting at index 60) and sorting the values in each series for ease of comparison:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df.iloc[60:, 0].sort_values(ignore_index=True))
plt.plot(df.iloc[60:, 1].sort_values(ignore_index=True), color='orange')
plt.ylim([0.605, 0.625]);
```

[image: tail comparison]

I don't know whether this is an artefact of how the data were recorded, or a real effect. In any case, note that the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is not appropriate here, because it assumes two random samples, wheras what you have are time series with the time clearly being a significant factor.

Comment: Ty, for your answer and the grammar adjustment, the difference is low, but there are many samples, so the 1/n ratio decrease in the D_n formula. I got this. However, I do not understand why I cannot use this test for time series. Can you explicit more or point me to a resource?

Comment: You're welcome. The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test assumes that for each of the two samples, all the data points are drawn independently from the same distribution (the i.i.d. assumption, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables). But in your data, every point is dependent (to some degree) of the previous one in the same series, so the i.i.d. assumption does not hold. I found some discussion of this over on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50798/two-sample-tests-for-time-series-segments

Comment: So a better approach would be to model the two time series, and then compare a parameter of interest between them. This package could be useful: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/tsa.html

Comment: Ty very much, I appreciate it